# Bash: Call script with an array of arguments

Tags: bash

Given a bash array, I'd like to call another script with that array as an argument. I expected that the ${X[@]} would do what I want, but that string concats the args, rather than passing args separately. For example:

```
X=()
X+='a'
X+='b'
./p.sh ${X[@]}
```

Calls p.sh with 1 arg whose value is 'ab'. I want to call p.sh with 2 args, the first being 'a' the second being 'b'.

Comment: You add array elements with `X+=('a')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `echo ${X[0]}` outputs `ab` which shows your `+=` appends to the first element. (The command `echo ${#X[@]}` outputs a `1` as well.)  Use

```
X=()
X+=('a')
X+=('b')
./p.sh "${X[@]}"
```

Comment: Thanks @chepner for the double quotes. It is a more correct answer.